# Is there any way to convert a LaTeX document to any Microsoft Word format, while retaining the document's structure?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex, documents, file-conversion

I'm currently working on a developer's manual to go with an application I'm making for work.  I wrote a simple script to go through all of my code, and parse all of my comments into a LaTeX document, and then added some additional reference material I wrote.  My work term is coming to an end soon, however, and I don't want to leave them stranded with a document they can't change or update in the future.

LaTeX is certainly **not** standard-issue stuff here, we use mostly Microsoft Office products.  My LaTeX document makes *extensive* use of in-document links to other sections (mainly with the `hyperref` package), so I'm trying my best to not have to rewrite the entire document.  This is why I would prefer to keep the *structure* of the document over the appearance (I can change appearance later, I just want to keep all of my crosslinks).

Is there any kind of application which can parse my TeX source, and convert it into an equivalent Microsoft Word document (any version is acceptable)?  Obviously, free/open source software would be preferred, but I'm willing to at least consider other paid alternatives.  Also, note that I don't have administrative privileges on this machine, so a portable solution would also be preferred.

Again, I'd really like to retain all of the cross-references and links to other document sections.  I'd prefer to keep the document structure over it's appearance.

---

**If anyone at any time has another solution (either another alternative, or a better method), please post it as an answer and it will be considered.  Thank you.**

Comment: Several ways to convert from LaTeX to Word are described [here on tug.org](http://www.tug.org/utilities/texconv/textopc.html).

Comment: Alternatively, it is certainly within scope at tex.stackexchange.com, which has already shown itself to be a source of excellent answers.  Consider asking it there, and then posting a link to the question here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [latex2rtf](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/) which I have used in the past (with RTF being something Word et al can read).  You will need some post-processing, but it is a start.

Comment: You could also use `latex2html` and then open it in Word. (http://www.latex2html.org)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Tex2Word](http://tex2word.com/) which works pretty well, although the formatting always needs some work.

Answer (score 2):

I usually go latex -> html -> import to openoffice -> save a .doc

This works best for me, but my latex docs have a ton of images. If you have just text or only a few figures, it should be much easier.

Comment: +1 for latex -> html -> openoffice -> doc. I'm doing it that way from the html part forward.

Answer (score 2):

I guess RTF is not an option due to missing hyperlinks. I've found two applications that claim to do it, however couldn't test them as I'm not on Windows.

---

#### [GrindEQ LaTeX-to-Word](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=latex2word)

This is shareware, but looks fairly promising.

> This module converts LaTeX, AMS-LaTeX, Plain TeX, or AMS-TeX documents to Microsoft Word format. You can choose the following formats for TeX/LaTeX equations: Microsoft Equation 2007, Microsoft Equation 3.x, or MathType. Works with Microsoft Word 97/2000/XP/2003/2007/2010 and Microsoft Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/7.

They seem to offer a commercial [online conversion service](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=service) as well.

---

#### [Chikrii Softlab TeX2Word](http://www.chikrii.com/products/tex2word/)

Also shareware, with a slightly cheaper looking website. Having a look at the manual wasn't very revealing in terms of cross-referencing capability though.

> TeX2Word is a converter designed in order to use with Microsoft Word and enables Microsoft Word to open documents in TeX format (this includes any TeX-based formats like LaTeX, etc.). This gives the opportunity to import existing TeX documents to Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.tug.org/utilities/texconv/textopc.html) is a a long tutorial on how to convert the LaTeX in other formats. May it helps you.
From some Googling I found that convert it into `HTML` format and then you can convert it into `.DOC` easily.

Also take a look on [TTH: Tex to HTML converter](http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/).
The source says 'It produces more compact, faster viewing, web documents than other converters, because it really translates the equations, instead of converting them to images.`

Comment: There's the hitec document class also: http://www.billauer.co.il/hitec.html. Also, have you tried a pandoc conversion?

Comment: There are additional suggestions here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/make-ms-word-document-look-like-it-has-been-typeset-in-latex